# Looping through Multidimention/Nested JSON data in Swift 5.1

Tags: json, swift, xcode, multidimensional-array, alamofire

I am trying to figure out how to handle complex multilevel JSON data in swift. I am able to get data at first level. However am unable to retrieve/loop through nested arrays in the JSON. So far I have this.

```
       let requestParams = ["appVersion" : "1.0.1" , "installId" : installId , "appToken" :  firebaseToken,
                         "phoneDimensions" : dimentions, "phoneOS" : "1", "os_version" :  systemVersion ]

        AF.request(startAppUrl, method: .post, parameters: requestParams , encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString{
            response in
            switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    let dataStr = data.data(using: .utf8)!

                    do{
                        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataStr , options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
                        let rows =  json!["ottHomeRows"] as!  [[String:Any]] //Nested Array

                        for item in rows{
                            print(item)
                        }

                    }
                    catch let error as NSError{
                        print("There is an error \(error)")

                    }

                case .failure(let error):
                    print((error.localizedDescription))
            }
        }
```

I have tried several variations of this but I always end up having issues casting the Nested array from type Any to an array.In the above code i get the error could not cast value of type __NSCString to NSArray.
Sample of my json data is here https://startv.co.tz/startvott/engine/jsonsample/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Swift Decoder for JSON:

```
struct SomeResult: Decodable {
    let usDeviceData: SomeResultUsDeviceData
}

struct SomeResultUsDeviceData: Decodable {

    let installId: String

    let appLang: SomeResultUsDeviceDataAppLang

    /// Encoder keys enum
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case installId = "install_id"
        case appLang = "appLang"
    }
}

struct SomeResultUsDeviceDataAppLang: Decodable {
    // and so on
}
```

to obtain a result use this:

```
let parsedResult = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SomeResult.self, from: data)
```

Comment: I now have this let dataStr = data.data(using: .utf8)!
let parsedResult = try? JSONDecoder().decode(appData.self, from: dataStr)

let rows =  parsedResult?.usDeviceData

for item in rows{
    print(item)
}

Comment: I get error Type 'ViewController.appDatausDeviceData?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'